# Auto-Resizing Heading on Bootstrap 3 site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fittextjs

How I create the resizable `<h1>` element on the getboostrap.com homepage for Bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

I know I can use tools like fittext.js but theirs adjusts by using CSS media queries it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `<h1>`tag in a [Jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron).
The default h1 font-size is 36px. You can use media queries to make it bigger:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1.resizable {
    font-size: 63px;
  }
}
```

You can add the `resizable`class to any h1 tag and it will make it bigger if the screen width is at minimum 768px.

Answer (score 1):

From their CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bs-masthead h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
}

.bs-masthead h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
}
```